# How to hydrate a drop down field in Kentico 8

Tags: kentico

I have a normal text field that is set to be a drop drop. I am currently trying to use a macro to do it.

Document["/News"].Children gives me the items I need, but not the correct display name. Its a field type.

Document["/News"].Children.Columns("NewsID,NewsTitle") seems to be the best bet, but does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
foreach(d in Documents["/News"].Children){d.DocumentName}
```

And also check out the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Macro+syntax#Macrosyntax-Iteration(loops)) to find out more about loops.

Comment: Thanks you. This seems to work. I have to see the selected value, but it looks good. Anyone who comes across this thread, here is the the SQL that worked for me.

SELECT CONTENT_News.NewsID, CONTENT_News.NewsTitle
FROM 
   View_CMS_Tree_Joined INNER JOIN CONTENT_News ON View_CMS_Tree_Joined.DocumentForeignKeyValue = CONTENT_News.NewsID 
WHERE 
   ClassName = 'CMS.News' AND (NodeParentID = 573)
AND 
   NewsReleaseDate <= GetDate() AND Published = 1